# Uploading base64encoded image to node.js/express server in Swift

Tags: ios, image, swift, upload, alamofire

I'm using Alamofire to make a network call where an image has to be uploaded as part of a larger "transaction" json object. I've encoded the image as base64. However, calling the checkout() function always times out. I've tried logging the request on the server, but it doesn't ever log anything. However, it works if I comment out the "json["photo"]" line. Any help would be great. Thanks!

```
func json() -> [String: AnyObject] {
    var json = [String: AnyObject]()
    json["id"] = Customer.id
    json["phone"] = Customer.phone
    json["photo"] = UIImagePNGRepresentation(Customer.photo).base64EncodedStringWithOptions(.allZeros)
    return json
}

func checkout(completion: (AnyObject?, NSError?) -> Void) {
    var params: [String: AnyObject] = [
        "transaction": json()
    ]
    Network.call("/1/checkout", params: params) { obj, err in
        completion(obj, err)
    }
}
```